# Best way to do calculation on a property of a Prop(coming from the parent) object and put the result in the template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an object that is being passed to the child component and I want to display those values in the child component template. However, the object contains properties that are arrays and objects so I need to do some parsing/manipulation on them before I set the value.

object:

```
{
  "id": "111",
  "ip": "10.192.1.112",
  "profiles": [
    "Japan",
    "Japan222"
  ],
  "network": [
    {
      "plan_id": "PLAN-UUID",
      "plan_name": "1BCT"
    },
    {
      "plan_id": "PLAN-UUID",
      "plan_name": "1BCT2"
    }
  ],
  "status": "LOCKED",
  "last_downloaded": "1547672769000"
}
```

template code in child:

```html
<label label="id" :value=this.objectFromParent.id />
<label label="ip" :value=this.objectFromParent.ip />
<label label="ip" :value= calculateProfiles />
```

where calculateProfiles is the method to calculate it and return the string value? I'm not sure what's a good way to handle this.

Comment: Use a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties)

Comment: ah computed prop worked. Thanks

Comment: Btw you don't need `this.` when binding. I'm not sure it works but people don't usually use `this.objectFromParent.id`, `objectFromParent.id` is enough

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <label label="id" :value="objectFromParent.id" />
    <label label="ip" :value="objectFromParent.ip" />
    <label label="ip" :value="calculateProfiles" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    objectFromParent: {
      type: Object,
      default() {
        return {
          id: '111',
          ip: '10.192.1.112',
          profiles: ['Japan', 'Japan222'],
          network: [
            {
              plan_id: 'PLAN-UUID',
              plan_name: '1BCT'
            },
            {
              plan_id: 'PLAN-UUID',
              plan_name: '1BCT2'
            }
          ],
          status: 'LOCKED',
          last_downloaded: '1547672769000'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    calculateProfiles() {
      return this.profiles.join(',')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

To help him on the comment:

```html
<label label="ip">
  <md-icon v-if="objectFromParent.status==='LOCKED'">lock</md-icon>
  {{calculateProfiles}}
</label>
```

Comment: thanks, but what if I need to add a lock symbol(<md-icon>lock</md-icon>) in front of the string if the "status: is locked? How would I insert md-icon code to the string I'm returning?

Comment: I think that's `<md-icon v-if="objectFromParent.status==='LOCKED'">lock</md-icon>`, use the directive `v-if`

Comment: I have to insert it into the :value part so that won't work. Let me know if you know of any other way.

Comment: I'm not sure, try the code I've put at the end of the answer to see if it works,